# ASP.NET Vnext GZiped Body Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

so I'm struggling with this a little bit, I can't quite wrap my head around it.  I've got an ASP.NET vNext application that's hosting MVC and WebAPI-style controllers.  The Controller in Question looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromQuery] string json, [FromBody]string item)
    {
        var requestBody = HttpContext.Request.Body;
        var postedData = json.JsonToDictionary();
        var deviceSerialNumber = postedData["deviceSerialNumber"].ToString();
        DateTime? endedAt = postedData["endedAt"] == null
            ? (DateTime?)null
            : DateTime.Parse(postedData["endedAt"].ToString());


        //var controlReference =
        //    _context.Controls.FirstOrDefault(
        //        ctrl => ctrl.SerialNumber == postedData["deviceSerialNumber"].ToString()) ?? new Control()
        //        {

        //        };
    }
```

My post data is a query string with the appropriate parameters as seen in the [FromQuery] section.  The ASP.NET binding picks up and can bind that correctly and my "json" parameter of the method gets a value.

However, the body of the Post is coming from an application outside of my control.  The body of the post is Gzip Compressed, and I can't bind any of the items [FromBody] until ASP.NET unzips the body.  Currently Vnext apps don't to this apparently.

In previous applications you could use this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, 
            new ServerCompressionHandler(
                new GZipCompressor(), 
                new DeflateCompressor()));
```

I don't believe that works in vNext applications though.

What else I've tried is:
modify the applicationhosts file to include the following lines:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
            <httpCompression>
                <dynamicTypes>
                    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
                    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />       
                </dynamicTypes>
            </httpCompression>
```

Which also hasn't had any affect that I can tell.  I can see the post coming in over Wireshark and it's able to decode the JSON in the body of the message without issue,  my .net 4.0 app also could decode the same message and bind the [FromBody] attribute once the GlobalFilter line was in.

Any advice?  I've found references to the response, but this is actually in the request body of a POST.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried creating the compression handler in the Controller and using it to decompress the post body?

Comment: Have an example of that @Richard Barker?

Comment: That also doesn't solve the overall problem. If I decompress it in the body, my model binding isn't going to work.